# parse XML from HTTP get request

Tags: java, html, xml

I'm using an API that returns XML in this format :

```
<response>
<status>OK</status>
<date>2015-11-25T09:15:40.11+01:00</date>
<page>1</page>
</response>
```

But when Im sending the request via java http I get HTML elements as response:

```
</plaincontent><htmlcontent><![CDATA[<div style="page-break-before:always; page-break-after:always"><div><div class="block"><p>
```

Inside the response, how to parse only the XML? withput the `div`s elements and CSS(the response is to long to post here).
I use `HttpClient`:

```
String URL = url.substring(1, url.length());
        //setting usr + pass Credentials with Realm
        client.getState().setCredentials(
                                new AuthScope(urlAuth, 443, "Realm"),
                                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "pass")
                            );

        GetMethod get = new GetMethod(URL);
        get.setDoAuthentication(true);
        try{
            int status = client.executeMethod(get);
            //System.out.println(status + "\n" + get.getResponseBodyAsString());
            //parsing XML from response
            System.out.println(get.getResponseBodyAsString());


        }finally{
            get.releaseConnection();
        }
```

Comment: What is the reason that you take a substring of your URL that starts at position 1?

Comment: Jusr to delete: " " (space )before the string.

Comment: Not what I was looking for.

Comment: Perhaps this question can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216462/how-to-get-response-as-xml-document-with-apache-httpclient-api

Comment: yes but I use httpClient that does not return httpresponse.

Comment: Add additional informations to your question what you mean about "parsing an XML"

Comment: Instead of the response with all the HTML elements I want the response as XML.